# Не работает клавиатура после выхода из сна (закрытие крышки ноутбука)

Tags: ubuntu

у меня довольно частая проблема, которую я не могу решить.

На ноуте Sony Vaio стоит новая Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. При закрытии крышки ноута и перехода в сон (а затем открытии), **встроенная клавиатура перестает работать.** Только тачпад, и то, секунда через 7-10. Система как бы висит эти секунды (стоит SSD, 4 Гб память, процесор i5). Включается, только если нажать, "сменить пользователя" и опять залогиниться под ним же. Если просто нажать на кнопку "заблокировать", то такая проблему не всречается.

Советы в интернете сводяться к устновке в drup параметров

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=" i8042.nopnp noacpi nolapic atkbd.reset quiet splash"
```

что мне не помогло, от слова совсем.

Можете пожалуйста подсказать, как решить эту проблему.

**Update**

После перебора параметров, нашел статью о том, как при похожей проблеме "удалили" rfkill файл. Мне это "помогло". Клавиатура, да и в принципе пробуждений происходит мгновенно (wi-fi конечно требует время на подключение, но это не критично), но систем начинает жутко висеть. gnome-shell процесс забирает все ресурсы. Потребление CPU сразу поднимается на 100%. Вернув файл на место, проблема с CPU осталась, но клавиатура работает. Что за магия?  Sony дружит только с windows?

Comment: попробуйте [разные директивы](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/04cbfba6208592999d7bfe6609ec01dc3fde73f5/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt#L1439) для контроллера i8042. [direct, dumpkbd](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056193/416190), reset=1 и т.д. и т.п. // atkbd вряд ли как-то повлияет — в ноутбуке явно не стандартный atkbd-контроллер.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin попробовал, не помогло... заметил, что клавиатура включается, если вверху мышкой сменить язык ввода. Может, можно установить другой драйвер?